# Better way of returning from condition

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Which way of returning from condition is better , Like the process1 and process 2 both does the same. But I want to know better way returning.
In both cases I don't want to enter inside of loop, I just want to return.  I would like to know that, Is there any performance difference If I put return before control passes to end. I don't want Java Virtual Machine to check end of loop and returning from there. I thought If I put return Immediately when the condition not satisfied, then I could see minor performance difference and also code readability. Please suggest me the best way. 
Let us consider the below scenarios.

Process1:

```
public Method()
{ //Method        
    Company company = new Company(); //Object
    if (null != Address && null = Address.location())  //Condition
    {
        return company; //I want to return
    }

        for (Location location: Address.location())
        {
            //forloop
        }

    return company; //return
}
```

Process2:

```
public Method()
{
    Company company = new Company();
    if (null != Address && null != Address.location()) 
    {
            //enters loop
    }
    return company; // return
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentations of your code sample ... it's really hard to read in it's current state.

Comment: This won't compile ... apart from that - pretty opinion based. Personally, I prefer single-point-of-return. But that's not carved in stone ...

Comment: one place `for` loop other place only `if`

Answer (score -1):

There will be some performance impact. Iterating complete objects from the for loop to verify the condition.

```
For example:

We can write like this.
if(condition is false){
  return ;
else{

   for(DataType ref: collection){
      if(true){
         return;// return from here, so that it will not iterate remaining elements.
      }
   } 
}


ex 2: 

if there is a logic after the if and that should not be executed, if the object is null.

if(object is null){

  return ;
}

//Remaining logic here will not be executed, if the object is null. it's a good way of writing.


ex 3: 

if there is no logic after the if and else, then directly return from the end of method.

if(object is null){
   return 
}else{
   //process logic and return. 
}

you can write something like this.

if(object is not null){
 // return either from here.
}
return here is also fine...
```

Comment: Please don't explain things outside of comments in your code.